# Basic Question over adding libraries to project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

1. I create a new project named XXX using Maven.
2. I do mvn eclipse:eclipse to to ensure it gets imported to Eclipse.

Now i am going to indite a Spring and Hibernate application. I need jars to be added. Where should i add them and How?

Please explain me in lame man language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you do what you'd always do in Maven. Add to the <dependencies/> element of your POM.

Then you re-rerun eclipse to get a new .classpath with the new stuff in it.

Comment: So you mean to say after i imported it into my IDE, i have to update the POM and the restart the eclipse.

Comment: No need to restart, just refreah and It'll re-read the .classpath.

Comment: Well i did create a project, then added it to eclipse then updated the POM and refreshed the project... nothing happened.. i still get errors in my java files

Comment: DId you rerun mvn eclipse:eclipse? Did you restart Eclipse just to see if it would help?

Answer (score 1):

Add them in your maven pom, then regenerate your project as you did originally.  Don't try to maintain dependencies in the project and your pom, as this will lead to inconsistencies.

As a better alternative, use the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) instead and then your eclipse and maven environments will be actually integrated.